# How to include version information into the setup output filename?

Tags: inno-setup

I have an application with version information which I would like to include into the setup output filename. For instance if the application have version `3.10.1` I would like to get `setup_3.10.1.exe` output file instead of a default `setup.exe` as an output file generated by Inno Setup.

Is it possible to include version information of a certain application into the setup output filename ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`OutputBaseFilename`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_outputbasefilename.htm) directive and assign to its value result of the [`GetFileVersion`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_getfileversion.htm) preprocessor function:

```
#define AppVer GetFileVersion('MyApp.exe')

[Setup]
OutputBaseFilename=setup_{#AppVer}
...
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It seems only absolute path works. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Neolisk Relative-path (to the ISS script location!) works just as well as absolute-path.